# JmsTemplate cannot send response because javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed

Tags: java, spring, connection, tibco

I have a standalone application using Spring to connect to TIBCO (queues). Occasionally, for various reasons, TIBCO connection is closed by the server. Most of the things are recovering from this. However, sometimes JmsTemplate is not able to send response because of the error below. I have a retry in place but the same error keeps coming (see trace below).

Details that may be important:

I am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer to get the request and send the response in that receiving thread. Also, I am using the same connection factory for both DefaultMessageListenerContainer and JmsTemplate.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:559)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:682)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:670)
        at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.send(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:149)
        at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._createProducer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:1067)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.createProducer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:5080)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doCreateProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1114)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.createProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:591)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
        ... 89 more
```

Communication with the TIBCO queue is done using Spring framework. Here is the configuration. A message is received by DefaultMessageListenerContainer, processed and JmsTemplate is used to send back the response. Connection factory is shared between receiver and sender (can this be an issue?).

```
    <bean id="connectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="tibcoJNDI" />
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                            <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="tibcoJNDI"/>
                            <property name="jndiName" value="${tibco.queueConnectionFactory}" />
                    </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>

    </bean>

<bean id="client.req.msg.lstnr" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="ext_client.request.queue"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="3"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="6"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000"/>
</bean>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter
    jms-template="ext.outbound.jms.template"
    channel="jms.to.ext.clnt.reply"/>

<bean id="ext.outbound.jms.template" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="ext_client.reply.queue"/>
    <property name="timeToLive" value="10800000" />
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>
```

One more detail that might help. I just noticed that the first exception is actually different. There is a "Connection is closed" exception first followed by multiple "Session is closed" exception (on retry).

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Connection is closed
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLink.sendRequest(TibjmsxLink.java:322)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLink.sendRequest(TibjmsxLink.java:286)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLink.sendRequestMsg(TibjmsxLink.java:261)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._createProducer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:1075)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.createProducer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:5080)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doCreateProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.createProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:591)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:484)
    ... 89 more
```

Comment: Please share the code that's causing the problem so that we can help diagnose the error. Thanks!

Comment: Hi CD, in the future, please edit your post with any code instead of putting it in a comment, it's much easier to read there!

Comment: Information added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Spring does not handle properly this case. I solved this issue by overriding JmsTemplate (code below) and handling the exception myself (cleaning the session and the connection). I hope this helps.

```
public <T> T execute(SessionCallback<T> action, boolean startConnection) throws JmsException {
    try {
        return super.execute(action, startConnection);
    } catch (JmsException jmse) {
        logger.error("Exception while executing in JmsTemplate (will cleanup session & connection): ", jmse);
        Object resourceHolder =
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getConnectionFactory());
        if (resourceHolder != null && resourceHolder instanceof JmsResourceHolder) {
            ((JmsResourceHolder)resourceHolder).closeAll();
        }

        throw jmse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24494739/208934 In particular:

> When using JMS you shouldn't really cache the JMS Session (and
>   anything hanging of that such as a Producer). The reason being is that
>   the JMS Session is the unit of work within JMS and so should be a
>   short lived object. In the Java EE world that JMS Session might also
>   be enlisted with a global transaction for example and so needs to be
>   scoped correctly.

It sounds like you're reusing the same session for multiple operations.

I have seen this problem in some of my tests and telling Spring to use a pool of connections usually fixes it. If you were using active-mq then it can be done with the property `spring.activemq.pooled=true`. I'm not 100% how Tibco accomplishes the same thing.

You might get get same results by defining a `PooledConnectionFactory` bean that will override the default.